# Is it possible to query a table without order columns by page

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a big table which contains more than 100K records, in oracle. I want to get all of the records and save each row to a file with JDBC.

In order to make it faster, I want to create 100 threads to read the data from the table concurrently. I will get the total count of the records in the first sql, then split it to 100 pages, then get one page in a thread with a new connection.

But I've a problem, that there is no any column can be used to order. There is no column with sequence, no accurate timestamp. I can't use a sql query without `order by` clause to query, since there is no guarantee it will return the data with the same order every time (per [this question](https://forums.oracle.com/message/9418084)).

So is it possible to solve it?

Comment: "I've a big table which contains more than 100K records" - No you don't!  If it had 100 billion rows in it, it would be large.

Comment: That's a small table but it's a big when you "save each row to a file". This being said, are you planning to do this frequently ? If not, you should not worry and just to it in one thread.

Comment: @dystroy: If each row was, say, 500 bytes (not an unfair assumption) with some overhead that would be approx. 60MB. Would you call a 60MB file large? I wouldn't...

Comment: @MitchWheat Neither I, of course. Maybe you didn't understand the same as me but I got that OP wanted to write 100K files.

Comment: Each row has a clob column, and the content is 6K. And I also have to write 100K files.

Comment: You should think also about the 100 threads. That makes only sense if you have 100 processors, and I don't belive that. I would really limit the cound of threads to the count of processors, except all threads have not much work, but this doesn't count in this case.

Comment: Alter the table and add a sequence column to it.  Then use that for your processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used `rowid` to order:

```
select * from mytable order by rowid
```

It seems work well.